# Avoiding duplicate queries in Django admin for __str__() with a foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In one model I want to reference my user's first and last name as the **str**() which is a foreign key to the User model.

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}"
```

My issue is, in some of the models on Django Admin, there are hundreds of queries which will obvious go to thousands with more users. What is the best practice around avoiding this? In some of my custom views there are duplicates here, but it's not as big of a deal as it is with the admin panel.

Answer (score -1):

Add to your ModelAdmin

list_select_related = ['user']

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just tried this, did not seem to have any effect.